# Magento RWD Theme: How Add Tags?

Tags: rwd, rwd-theme, tags

I am using Magento 1.9's RWD theme.

It does not display tags. You don't have the option to tag products on the frontend. There is no box that shows existing tags. And going to the page that should show tags (/tag/list/) gives a blank.

I read in the knowledge base that "Responsive design was not implemented for the following: ... Tags ..."

So is there a way to display tags on the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/tag.xml` file, you will see that all layout XML was removed, which essentially disabled the Tag functionality. If you copy the contents of `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/tag.xml` into that layout file, the tag functionality should show up. However it will not be styled, so you will need to write styles to ensure that it matches your theme.

Comment: This is the correct answer, from a Llama himself.

Comment: Thank you very much! 

The tags reappeared where they should be. But if I click on one of the tags (to see all the products that are tagged with that tag), the page displays: "Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 134"

Comment: I figured it out from here. Basically, tag.xml will work with the list.phtml from Base, but not from RWD. So I copied and renamed list.phtml from Base and told tag.xml to look to that file. Then I just had to edit the format (resize the images, add a div class), and now it looks like the rest of the site. Thanks again!